# How to integrate dependencies from Github in Grails?

Tags: grails, github, grails-2.0

Is it possible to integrate sources from github in Grails BuildConfig.groovy? Normally, you would use the dependancy or the plugin section to integrate sources, but how can I integrate snapshots from Github?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you follow the expected layout structure, it shouldn't be a problem.
Just push your artifacts at the right location.

Check this layout structure -> https://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/

In your project, you would a repository definition such as this one:

```
grailsRepo("http://githubURL", "githubRepo")
```

Comment: Can your be more specific please. What do you mean by "the expected layout structure"? How would I specify a certain repo?

Comment: It's just a matter of creating folders in github and dumping your snapshot zip files in there. As mentioned previously look at the "layout structure" that can be found here : https://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/